# Add current date to file name of message attachment in vbs script

Tags: vbscript, outlook, attachment

I am using 
Script.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

and I want to add an attachment that has a file name equivalent to the current date.

This what I am using and it works to find a specific file

MessageAttachment = "C:\Personal\Complaints Assigned to Lacker 0600 09-19-2013.xlsx"

but I want it to look for this where MM-DD-YYYY is the current date.

MessageAttachment = "C:\Personal\Complaints Assigned to Lacker 0600 MM-DD-YYYY.xlsx"

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Construct the path with the (custom-formatted) current date:

```
MessageAttachment = "C:\Personal\Complaints Assigned to Lacker 0600 " & _
    & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(Now), 2) & "-" _
    & Year(Now) & ".xlsx"
```